# Is the validity of the Skolemization of a sentence A infers the validity of A?

Tags: logic

I have a claim I need to prove or disprove. Let Sk(A) be the Skolemization of A (A is a sentence).
If Sk(A) is valid then A is also valid.

In other exercise I was asked if A is valid then Sk(A) is also valid, but I think I disproved it with a counter example(if it is right then please let me know hehe)

I think that its true that if Sk(A) is valid then A is also valid, but I don't know how to show that.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: What does *valid* mean? In a given $L$-structure? The language has changed, and one technically needs to provide an interpretation for the new constant symbols/function symbols. However, under *any* such interpretation, if the Skolemization is valid, then the sentence is.

Comment: "I was asked if A is valid then Sk(A) is also valid, but I think I disproved it with a counter example" Example?

Answer (score 2):

Skolemization is refutation complete but not validation 
complete. Means if you have a theory T, and its 
skolemization T^S, you will know:

```
T |= [] iff T^S |= [].
```

This is why skolemization is often found in theorem 
proving. For validity you would need Herbrandization 
which will attack forall quantifiers and not existential 
quantifiers. With Herbrandization one has:

```
[] |= T iff [] |= T^H
```

Both Skolemization and Herbrandization are based on 
the following higher order identity and its dual
which can be obtained by negating both sides:

```
forall x exists y A(x,y) <-> exists f forall x A(x,f(x))
```

The identity makes use of the axiom of choice in one
direction. The quantification of the functorial f is 
delegated to the signature of the first order theory
and the definition of the |= sign.

Possibly Skolemization and Herbrandization can be 
combined, but I wouldn't confuse it with Morleyization
since both Skolemization and Herbrandization introduce
function symbols and not relation symbols.